# Getting Specific Content of a Webpage

Tags: android

Yo,

How would I go about getting only part of a webpages information? The webpage content I want changes every time the page loads.
The webpage is made up of javascript inside HTML, the javascript updates the values I need. Here is a link to the webpage: http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00444250/tracker/ the content I want is between Latitude and space.

If this isn't possible whats the best way to get this content for my app?

Thanks

Comment: `preg_replace ( '#\D*?(\d+(\.\d+)?)\D*#', '$1', $string );`

You can modify that for your purposes. Will filter all but numbers and decimals.

Comment: Can you please clarify this a little. Can you give me an example if possible?

Comment: If you can use regular expressions, then you can use the above code, `#\D*?(\d+(\.\d+)?)\D*#` to filter out all text from it, leaving you with just the raw numbers and decimal points. I can't help you further though, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cannot execute javascript without WebView...

Wouldn't it be better in this case to get data directly and parse it as JavaScript on this webpage does?